# Can't retrieve images from application in Docker container

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm trying to dockerize a python/django application. When Docker runs the build script in a web container, it is unable to retrieve the images from application.
It shows an error:
[image: docker error]

and on Google chrome console it shows:
[image: Chrome Console error]

But what is interesting is that I don't get any errors when I do the same on my local machine.
Everything goes as expected.

Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40

Comment: Can we see the Dockerfile? is there any .dockerignore file?

Comment: Do you have some *.pyc  on your local / docker env?

Comment: here is my docker file: 
https://imgur.com/iY0q5Qj  
i dn't have any .dockerignore file.